# displaytag click on a page number

Tags: displaytag

I use displaytag to show a list with pagination.
in the first display everything works, except that clicking next or a page number, I get the page but in another div.

I'm using spring and struts 2 and this is the first time I use displaytag.
Here the code of my display tag

```
<display:table  style="width:100%"  name="myList" class="MyObjectClass" uid="row" id="row" pagesize="10"   requestURI="myAction!myMethod.action">                   >
  <display:column title="My First Property" property="property1"></display:column>
  <display:column title="My 2nd Property" property="property2"></display:column>
  <display:column title="My Last Property" property="property3"></display:column>
</display:table>
```

How can I do to stay on the same target of the first by clicking the number of a page

Answer (score 0):

for interested I solved the problem
I added this code to my jsp page

```
$('span.pagelinks>a, table#displayTab>thead>tr>th>a').live('click', function () {
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, status, xmlHttpRequest) {
        $('#displayTagDiv').html($('#displayTagDiv', responseText).html());
    })
    return false;
})
```

`displayTagDiv` is the div that contains my displaytable `displayTab`

I also redefines the property next / previous ...